# Write output to a file after piped to jq

Tags: shell, io-redirection

How can I write a piped output that went through `jq` to a file in shell

Example:

```
curl api.example.com | jq > call.txt
```

won't work. Neither does

```
(curl api.example.com | jq) > call.txt
```

Help!

Edit: So doing `curl api.example.com > call.txt` works just fine. So it has to do with piping it to [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq)

Comment: What output is it?

Comment: @iBug it should not matter what output it is, but it is JSON

Comment: Did you verify there *is* any output when you don't redirect it?

Comment: @ibug yes, it writes it to the shell

Comment: Which OS, distribution and version do you use?

Comment: @Cyrus MacOS, High Sierra, zsh (mentioned bash to reach more people)

Comment: What error do you see? What does `jq --version` give you?

Comment: @Attie v1.5, I realised why it fails silent. When the file is existing and I leave the `.` out, the stderr of the failed `>` because the file existed overwrote the output of `jq` for the missing `.`. Have a test yourself. Do `curl https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 | jq > test.txt` when `test.txt` is already existing. No error from jq

Comment: Interesting observation, though I see the error whether `test.txt` exists or not...

Comment: zsh is not bash, and is not compatible with bash. Your effort to "reach more people" is liable to make some of them grumpy.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy people who get upset by this should better leave the question alone. Fact is that this error is not zsh specific...

Comment: It isn't, but if you want non-shell-specific answers, that's what the `sh` and `shell` tags are for. It's like tagging `c++` for a C question -- sure, *much of the time* the language is a superset, but anyone who actually *wanted* C questions would be following the C tag.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy not 100% sure if c++ comparison to c is the same as zsh to bash, but I see your point. I have amended it

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Just calling `jq` without a filter will throw errors if `stdout` isn't a terminal

```
$ curl https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 | jq > test.txt
jq - commandline JSON processor [version 1.5-1-a5b5cbe]
Usage: jq [options] <jq filter> [file...]

        jq is a tool for processing JSON inputs, applying the
        given filter to its JSON text inputs and producing the
[...]
```

Try `jq '.'` (i.e: pretty-print the input JSON):

```
$ curl https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 | jq '.' > test.txt
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   292  100   292    0     0   1698      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1707
```

---

Note that the filter is not really optional:

From `man jq`:

```
JQ(1)                                                                                JQ(1)

NAME
       jq - Command-line JSON processor

SYNOPSIS
       jq [options...] filter [files...]
```

---

According to the tip of the master branch... your described (and my observed) behaviour is not expected...

Older versions of `jq` have the following: ([here](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/d66fbd2/main.c#L467-L468))

```c
if (!program && isatty(STDOUT_FILENO) && !isatty(STDIN_FILENO))
  program = ".";
```

i.e: use a default filter if `stdout` *is* a TTY, and `stdin` *is not* a TTY.

This behaviour appears to be corrected in commit [5fe05367](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/commit/5fe05367#diff-803c5170888b8642f2a97e5e9423d399R472), with the following snippet of code:

```c
if (!program && (!isatty(STDOUT_FILENO) || !isatty(STDIN_FILENO)))
  program = ".";
```

Comment: when I run `curl api.example.com | jq` it gives me a pretty printed output of the JSON I just curled. How can write this to a file without saving it to a json first.

Comment: You must specify the filter, to pass everything through give the filter as "`.`" - e.g: `curl api.example.com | jq . > call.txt`

Comment: can you amend your question to make it work with `curl`? The `"."` doesn't work for me neither

Comment: sorry my fault, it works fine with `.` or `"."`. But I don't understand, why can I not take the output printed to the shell. What does the `.` to make a difference

Comment: `.` is the most basic "_do nothing_" filter... `jq` clearly has some logic to assume that if no filter is given, _and_ the output is a PTY, then use the filter `.`... If the output is not a PTY (e.g: it's a file), then this assumption is not made.

Comment: thanks, could you amend the cat to curl example and then I will accept :)

Comment: thanks, but I was at least expecting any error output for the missing filter. Thats just breaking silent

Comment: Working fine. How to export to CSV with heading?

Answer (score 26):

My incantation:

```
$ cat config.json

{
    "ProgramSettings":
    {
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "ProgramSecrets":
    {
        "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": "",
        "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": ""
    }
}
```

assume you want remove object 'ProgramSecrets' from JSON file:

```
$ echo $(cat config.json | jq 'del(.ProgramSecrets)') > config.json
$ cat config.json
{ "ProgramSettings": { "version": "1.0" } }
```

Comment: although interesting to know, this does not provide any answer to the above question.

Comment: This will likely also stamp on `config.json` ... i.e: `> config.json` will truncate it before `cat config.json` can get a chance to read it.

Comment: Oh wow this is literally what was happening to me @Attie. But it was intermittent in CI and doing my head in. I now just copy the file first and then delete the copy afterwards.

Comment: @simesy - you might like to take a look at `sponge`!

Comment: Thanks @Attie I would never have known about this, never heard of it before!

Comment: @supersize This answer actually works for me, because it captures the jq output and echos it to the file, where redirecting the jq output directly to the file was failing

Comment: I have tried like this and it worked. `cat manifest.json | jq ".version |= \"${VERSION}\"" --indent 4 | tee manifest.json`

Comment: @supersize "this does not provide any answer to the above question" it literally answers the question better than the accepted answer...

Answer (score 5):

Just try:

```
curl api.example.com | jq '.' > call.txt
```

It works fine for me.